# What does '*' do as a parameter in discord.py?

Tags: python, discord.py

I want to know what does asterisk do as a parameter in ban_user function?. In which situations do we use it? What's its advantage against ***args**?

```py
import discord
from discord.ext import commands


intents = discord.Intents(messages=True, guilds=True, reactions=True, members=True,presences=True)


client = commands.Bot(command_prefix="!dc ", intents=intents)


@client.command(aliases=["ban"])
@commands.has_role("admin")

async def ban_user(ctx, member: discord.Member, *, reason=None):
    await member.ban(reason=reason)

client.run(Token)
```

Comment: @luk2302 oh yeah thanks

Answer (score 0):

It makes it so all content/provided args after member count as the reason. basically just specify's that all following words are also part of the reason argument.